# Extremely oversized/large buttons inside Kivy Screen class

Tags: python, user-interface, graphics, kivy

For the sake of brevity I'll explain my problem before posing the code. Here it goes:

I have a `Screen` class in Kivy that holds two widgets, a `GridLayout` and an `Image`. The latter is fine, but the buttons are extremely oversized:

[image]

And here's my main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import configparser

Builder.load_file('kv\MainMain.kv')

#read configurations
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

#read config values
width = config.getint('Default', 'MAX_WINDOW_WIDTH')
height = config.getint('Default', 'MAX_WINDOW_HEIGHT')
border = config.getint('Default', 'BORDERLESS')

#apply config values
Config.set('graphics','width', width)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', height)
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', border)
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')


#create screen manager
class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


#create background widget
class BackGround(Image):
    pass


#image buttons
class MainButtons(GridLayout):
    pass



#create main screen:
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


#create main app
class MainMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

#register class
Factory.register(MainScreen, cls=MainScreen)

#run
if __name__ == '__main__':
   MainMainApp().run()
```

And here's my kv file:

```
<ScreenManager>:
    id: screen_manager

    MainScreen:
        id: main_screen
        name: 'MainScreen'
        manager: screen_manager

    ReadScreen:
        id: read_screen
        name: 'ReadScreen'
        manager: screen_manager


<MainScreen>:

    BackGround:
        id: back_ground
        source: 'images\\app_background.jpg'
        size: root.width, root.height


    MainButtons:
        cols: 1
        pos: root.width / 2 - 100, root.height / 4
        size: 20, 10

        Button:
            id: button_read
            text: "Read"
            on_press: root.callback_read()

        Button:
            id: button_add
            text: "Add"

        Button:
            id: button_manage
            text: "Manage"
```

I'm really swamped on this one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use size_hint for this.

Here is an example
The pyhton file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager

Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MainButtons(GridLayout):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main"))
        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
   MainMainApp().run()
```

and kivy file:

```
<MainScreen>:
    MainButtons:
        cols: 1
        rows: 4
        Label:
            font_size: "40sp"
            text: "Something"

        Button:
            size_hint: (1,0.1)
            text: "Read"

        Button:
            size_hint: (1,0.1)
            text: "Add"

        Button:
            size_hint: (1,0.1)
            text: "Manage"
```

And output will be:

[image]

And if you want the buttons to be smaller in width, you add ´size_hint_x: None´ to your kv file, like this.

```
<MainScreen>:
    MainButtons:
        cols: 1
        rows: 4
        Label:
            font_size: "40sp"
            text: "Something"

        Button:
            size_hint: (1,0.1)
            size_hint_x:None
            text: "Read"

        Button:
            size_hint: (1,0.1)
            size_hint_x:None
            text: "Add"

        Button:
            size_hint: (1,0.1)
            size_hint_x:None
            text: "Manage"
```

Output will now be:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. The buttons are still gigantic. It worked fine when the class was just a widget, but now that it's a screen, they became gigantic.

Comment: Yes, it works fine if the class is a Widget. But that was not my problem at the first place. I want the Screen class to work.

Comment: @Chubak it works with GridLayout. And your MainButtons is basically just a gridlayout. Only you shall remember to tell it how many rows you got.

Comment: Your code works, which means there's an unfixable problem with mine because no matter how much I try, I still get those ginormous buttons. Thank you. I have to start over but it's fine.

Comment: I actually did create one with screen, and it worked fine. Which means if I start over, it'll work. I know what I'm doing is not conventional and I have to try to fix my code, which is why I'll try to do that before starting over.

Comment: I fixed my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chubak ok. Anyways I uppdated it, with screen. Same output.